# Dash Plotly Authorization linked to website credentials

Tags: joomla, plotly-dash

I am looking to implement a login to access my Dash Plotly web app, however, I am looking to incorporate the login credentials from my Joomla website. Users will register and sign up on my website then gain access to my dash web app. However once gaining access I will need them to be able to log directly in from the web app itself.

I know I can use Dash basic auth however that may prove slightly difficult based on what I want to do, Is there any advice as to where I should look or a process I should look into?

Many Thanks,

Comment: You can also use Flask auth libraries like Flask login. There are Dash specific auth libraries other than dash auth which you can find on Github, but I haven't used those so I can't vouch for them. Having said this, I think this question doesn't fit that well on SO. I recommend looking for threads / posting a question on the [plotly forum](https://community.plotly.com/).

Comment: Thanks Bas, I will go check out the various Dash Auth forks, maybe I can find something suitable over there, appreciate it

Comment: @DevinSmith if you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.